# "The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility" RN 0.73

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

Por questões de incompatibilidade de versões, precisei atualizar um aplicativo da empresa onde trabalho em react native da versão 0.60 para a 0.73. Depois de fazer milhares de atualizações não só no projeto como também no java do computador (um mac mini), no NodeJS, no SDK, no JDK, no Android Studio... enfim, em praticamente tudo relacionado a programação mobile, toda vez que eu tento executar o projeto, dá sempre o mesmo erro: "The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility":
[image]
Preciso atualizar o app rápido para corrigir erros da última atualização, então preciso resolver isso imediatamente, mas nada que eu tentei ou procurei na internet deu resultado. Alguém sabe como resolver essa situação?
O Gradle-wrapper.properties:
[image]

O build.gradle (android):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.20'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "20.7.0"
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.22"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

//def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            //force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
            //force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + "0.60.5"
            //force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + "0.73.5"
            //force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            println repo.url.toString()
            if (repo.url.toString().startsWith("https://jcenter.bintray.com/")) {
                project.logger.warn "Repository ${repo.url} removed."
                remove repo
                mavenCentral()
            }
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        exclusiveContent {
           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

Preciso de uma resposta válida o quanto antes, se alguém puder...